# "where" on joined field in a left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to make a self join which I did using LEFT JOIN but now I'd like to join 2 other tables and add a where on 2 of the fields of the joined table. The data table contains a self reference to its parent ID. I'd like to get the child name AND the parent name for a given CATEGORY and TYPE. I tried the following request:

```
SELECT d1.NAME as NAME, d1.Parent as Parent, d2.NAME as PARENT_NAME 
FROM data as d1 LEFT OUTER JOIN data as d2 ON d1.PARENT = d2.ID 
        JOIN TYPE ON d1.T_ID
        JOIN CATEGORY ON d1.CAT_ID
        WHERE TYPE_NAME = 'Name'
        AND CAT_NAME = 'Name'
```

But the result is the same with out without the "where" meaning that I get all the result for all CATEGORY and all the TYPE.

Comment: Qualify all columns, we don't know which table which column belongs to... (i.e. just like d1.NAME, both table and column name!)

Comment: Actually NAME is the column name

Comment: Please provide further information, like the table structure, sample data, and the expected output

Comment: From which table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JOIN` conditions are incomplete, so you are effectively getting a `CROSS JOIN` instead since wherever `T_ID` and `CAT_ID` are not 0 or `NULL` a `JOIN` will happen. Try changing them to (assuming the `ID` columns in the `TYPE` and `CATEGORY` tables are called `ID`):

```
JOIN TYPE ON d1.T_ID = TYPE.ID
JOIN CATEGORY ON d1.CAT_ID = CATEGORY.ID
```

Comment: I feel so dumb, i'm use to use "join using" and since it wasn't working i used "join on" but forget that about "join on" ... Thanks !

Comment: @Xilamax an easy thing to do. It's one of the reasons I only use `JOIN ON`.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct your **join condition** at the time of joining

```
SELECT d1.NAME as NAME, d1.Parent as Parent, d2.NAME as PARENT_NAME 
FROM data as d1 
LEFT OUTER 
JOIN data as d2 ON d1.PARENT = d2.ID 
JOIN TYPE ON d1.T_ID **= someColumn**
JOIN CATEGORY ON d1.CAT_ID  **= someColumn**
WHERE TYPE_NAME = 'Name'
AND CAT_NAME = 'Name'
```